# iterating through json object Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm having a really hard time trying to find a way to iterate through this JSON object in the way that I'd like. I'm using only Typescript here.

First, here's the object

```
   date1: {enabled: false, label: "Date1 Label", eformVisible: false, mandatory: "NOT_MANDATORY", order: 20}
date2: {enabled: false, label: "Date2 Label", eformVisible: false, mandatory: "NOT_MANDATORY", order: 21}
date3: {enabled: false, label: "Date3 Label", eformVisible: false, mandatory: "NOT_MANDATORY", order: 22}
date4: {enabled: false, label: "Date4 Label", eformVisible: false, mandatory: "NOT_MANDATORY", order: 23}
date5: {enabled: false, label: "Date5 Label", eformVisible: false, mandatory: "NOT_MANDATORY", order: 24}
dropdown1: {enabled: true, label: "Country", eformVisible: false, mandatory: "NOT_MANDATORY", order: 30, …}
dropdown2: {enabled: false, label: "Dropdown2 Label", eformVisible: false, mandatory: "NOT_MANDATORY", order: 31,}
dropdown3: {enabled: false, label: "Dropdown3 Label", eformVisible: false, mandatory: "NOT_MANDATORY", order: 32, }
dropdown4: {enabled: false, label: "Dropdown4 Label", eformVisible: false, mandatory: "NOT_MANDATORY", order: 33,}
dropdown5: {enabled: false, label: "Dropdown5 Label", eformVisible: false, mandatory: "NOT_MANDATORY", order: 34,}
```

I did loop through the object. and now add need to bind data to html  elements based on **text or dropdown enabled  true value** how can I use ngfor loop foreach textbox and dropdown which don't have same index . I like to do exactly patch form .
so I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Did you try using `Object.entries()`?

Comment: yes,but not getting exact output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) syntax in combination with [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to achieve this.

```js
const options = {
  "text1": {
    "enabled": true,
  },
  "text2": {
    "enabled": false,
  },
  "dropdown1": {
    "enabled": true,
  },
  "dropdown2": {
    "enabled": false,
  },
  "dropdown3": {
    "enabled": false,
  },
};

for ([key, value] of Object.entries(options)) {
  if (value.enabled) {
    if (key.startsWith('text')) {
      console.log('enable text', key);
    } else if (key.startsWith('dropdown')) {
      console.log('enable dropdown', key);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for ur explantion.its almost there need to do somechanges for typescript thanks alot for your help

Answer (score 1):

try using `for in` loop to iterate,

```
const items: any = {
    "text1": {
        "enabled": true,
    },
    "text2": {
        "enabled": false,
    },
    "dropdown1": {
        "enabled": true,
    },
    "dropdown2": {
        "enabled": false,
    },
    "dropdown3": {
        "enabled": false,
    },
};

for (let item in items) {
    console.log(item);
    console.log(items[item]);
}
```

Playground link: [Click here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAllApgWwgLhgQzATxgXhgG8BYAKBkpgCIkAPKARmo1Iqo+sTEwCMAbRABMWMKACcArogA05DgF857SrUQMATKLYdO3PoJEYAZpn4RZ8qkquqh4kAAchIAO5hmrW7q48Bw0QlpZUUQqmp7Jxd3LS8VH31-IxhTc0t4m3iIh2c3MABmbW89P0NRVIswykyFAG5ycmMQcRgACkFYBBR4MHgkVABKYm9QSBBBADp+EABzVq7kAfr40YhxxCnZ+f6IAG0FgF0l8gUgA)